# Сворачивается окно чата после отправки сообщения

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the chat form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup chat - hidden by default */
.chat-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width textarea */
.form-container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 200px;
}

/* When the textarea gets focus, do something */
.form-container textarea:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/send button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>


<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Chat</button>

<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/chat" method="post" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 100px" class="form-container">{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Chat</h1>

    <label for="your_name"><b>Message</b></label>
      <p style="margin-left: 10px">{{ name }}</p>
    <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="your_name" required id="your_name" type="text"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" >Send</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Нужно чтобы чат не сворачивался пока не нажмут кнопку "Close"
Если убрать

> display: none;

то чат не сворачивается  но сразу развёрнут при переходе на страницу,а мне надо чтобы он был свёрнут,и открыт когда на него нажмут.
Я вижу одно решение убрать display: none; и добавить скрипт который сворачивает чат при переходе на страницу(так чтобы юзер это не заметил) подскажите как это реализовать на JS или подскажите своё решение этой проблемы.
Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно сделать чат через ajax. Тогда ничего не будет закрываться после отправки сообщения

Comment: у вас отправка формы перезагружает страницу, поэтому и закрывается чат